# Does the passport contain the address?

Tags: usa, passports, esta

I am going to travel to the USA, from Europe, and I am filling the ESTA.

I moved very recently to another country within the EU and I am in doubt which address I should use.

In my passport my address is nowhere visible, but I don't know if it's recorded since it's an electronic passport.

I am afraid that if I use my new address for the ESTA the information mismatches the one on the passport and I get in trouble for something so simple.

Comment: Use your current address, not the one you had when you obtained the passport.

Comment: It might help if you told us which country issued the passoprt.....

Comment: Use the current address, that's it

Answer (score 4):

While the ESTA form does ask for your contact information, it means your current address and not one you provided as part of country's passport application. As you point out, your passport doesn't show an address, many don't.

What the [ESTA online application](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html) will ask is your passport information, parents' names, city of birth, history of US visa admissions, contact information, and any criminal history, any national identification number you may have, history of communicable disease.

Comment: I have never heard of any passport that contained an address. AFAIK the US passport chips contain just a reference ID the EU passports the same data as the id page (including your photo) and your fingerprints.

Comment: @chx nor have I, but made found some anecdotal reports that suggests some do, so I didn't want to make such a broad generalization that none contain addresses.

Comment: French passports do contain the adress you had when you applied for it. Needless to say, this address is often out of date and completely useless, and one's current address should be used in an ESTA.